# Pymodm: ImportError (Two models referencing each other)

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymodm

I'm writing a todo app using flask and mongoDB and  Pymodm as an ODM. 
I have two models named User and UserGroups. these two reference each other like so:

**user.py**

```
from api.models.userGroup import group
class User(MongoModel):
   _id    = fields.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   email  = fields.CharField()
   password  = fields.CharField()
   createdAt = fields.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
   groups = [fields.ReferenceField('group')]
   personalTodoLists = fields.EmbeddedDocumentListField('list')
```

**userGroup.py**

```
from api.models.user import user
class UserGroup(MongoModel, EmbeddedMongoModel):
   _id    = fields.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name  = fields.CharField()
   createdAt = fields.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
   ownerId = fields.ReferenceField('user')
   contributors = [fields.ReferenceField('user')]
   todoLits = fields.EmbeddedDocumentListField('list')
```

I'm getting the error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'user'"

How can i make references in this case properly?

Comment: This is an `ImportError`, and you're missing the (relevant) `import` sentences from each module. I can guess them, but please add them for clarity. Also, I can tell you in advance that you Python doesn't handle circular references in imports. A module must be fully processed before you can import it (which can't happen if two modules import each other)

Comment: Thanks, i'm using Blueprint to define modules. I'll add the import sentences. do you have any idea how to make references in this case?

Comment: Note: I'm not familiar with pyMODM, but given how other ORM interfaces work, I think the list here is not needed: `[fields.ReferenceField('group')]` (same for the reference in the other class.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular reference is a common problem with many-to-many relationships. The usual solution implemented by the packages is to provide you with a way to refer to (yet to be defined) other model using a string with its name, instead of the object itself.

I can see that's what you've done, actually. Eg:

```
    groups = [fields.ReferenceField('group')]
```

There should be no need for you to actually *import* those models, then. Just comment out/remove the offending import lines, and it should work.

Comment: Cool. As a general rule, try to import *class names* and use them as references, whenever possible. Using a string like this should be a last resort for cases like the one you're having here, because there's no other way. But using the string with the name ties you to the actual name used in the database, which is typically predictable, but introduces a dependence on implementation details.